# Numpy 2D or 3D array axis wise sum

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to use numpy's np.sum() but the axis value is confusing me, I am not sure how to think about the sum/ intuition of 3D array sum.

I am fine when its 2D array.

can any one guide me to a good link or make me understand how to thing about it ?

[image: IMG]

Comment: You have a 3D array, so `axis=-1` is the same with `axis=2`. What's so confusing to you?

Comment: Yes, I understoop -1 is the last dimension, but how is it calculated '

Comment: Say, you have a list of n 2D arrays. `axis=0` sums all those arrays, `axis=1` sums columns of those arrays, `axis=2` sums rows of those arrays. In the resulting 3x3 array with `axis=-1`, the first column is `[0+0, 576+49, 841+1]`, all coming from the first 2D array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some findings ,I tried to create a handdrawn diagram to explain what axis wise calculation means for Numpy.
I used different example to explain it for simplicity :

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

I think, but I don't know, the idea here is that you're only reducing the dimensionality of the array by one.  So if you've got a 3d array then your sums are going to be 2d arrays in the X, Y or Z direction depending on the axis you select.

It also seems as though you could reduce the dimensionality by two instead of one by passing in multiple axes.  So you could get a 1d array from a 3d array by passing `axis=[0,1]` or `axis=[1,2]` or `axis=[0,2]`

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html